# How do I reinstall Bonjour

Tags: windows

Should I reinstall Bonjour after I got an message : File Problem: M DNSResponse.exe
How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This might be more relevant on superuser.com but here's the steps

1. Go to the Control Panel and click on Add or Remove Programs.
2. Select Bonjour from the list.
3. Click Change/Remove.
4. Choose Remove, then follow the onscreen instructions.
5. Reinstall Bonjour for Windows from the Apple website, or the media on which it was supplied to you.