# How can I remove or disable Bonjour on OSX Lion, is it safe?

Tags: macos, bonjour

I have the only one computer with OSX (wife hates OSX) so I have no other computer to bonjour with. I never needed neither network zero-configuration nor printer sharing or whatever it does. Windows it causes [MDNSResponder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/how-do-i-reinstall-bonjour) problems.

How can I remove or disable Bonjour service?
Is it safe?

Comment: Should we assume you want to uninstall / disable this service on OSX?

Comment: @bmike, nevermind. I should really Google better before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot remove Bonjour from MacOS X. There is no real good reason to do so anyway.

Also the "problem" you link to describes an issue with Bonjour installed on Windows 7, so it does not apply to you.

Answer (score 3):

As Gerry said it's a bad idea.
Just removing mDNSResponder will also break DNS resolver.

However it's possible to disable Bonjour service advertisements. It can be achieved by adding value '-NoMulticastAdvertisements' to the array in the "ProgramArguments" section.

That's well described in [Apple knowledge base article](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT3789#) and [on Charles Edge's site](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/disabling-bonjour/).

Comment: And how is Bonjour re-enabled: is it simply that the array value changes to "-MulticastAdvertisements"